# Error In Image generation, Using GD:Graph In Perl

Tags: perl

Well I'm learning Perl, and I was thought of trying out the for Graphics like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use CGI ':standard';
use GD::Graph::bars;
use strict;

# Both the arrays should same number of entries.
my @data = (["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
             "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            [23, 5, 2, 20, 11, 33, 7, 31, 77, 18, 65, 52]);

my $mygraph = GD::Graph::bars->new(500, 300);
$mygraph->set(
    x_label     => 'Month',
    y_label     => 'Number of Hits',
    title       => 'Number of Hits in Each Month in 2002',
) or warn $mygraph->error;

my $myimage = $mygraph->plot(\@data) or die $mygraph->error;

print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
print $myimage->png;
```

when I execute the code, I get an output like this:

```
5���]�g�?>��l-�q��0H���9��c�_>~u��#�Q�1i3ı�
q����@.w�T�ˁ�!aage/png
                �[�r��0���?p?�<�YV��W*�8`���g���)�F�fNs�����I��ǑH���ט0�N��R_4�����3\����!��<�/g���K�Y����w{����Nwc�~�~�;���?yJ��m�j�ށ_
                                                    ���c���Ϯ��(�����s^
�����[p�����a�G�����B����*-��s����UO�O��`�
              PLTE������ktRNS@��f�IDATx����0�k/���ϼ|��;�?t|IuP�����O�?.�����ӿd�?�w�&�K+=\�_'���q�p}2.��X���~S�j5>��G��&v��0>�:W������]r6���7U�T��Pn����O��� s�����|�:��^R���!���O1�/o�S�������4;�%��Hv5����C��u�xS1y�ː7"N���yb������hFّ��B��"���v�kR�i���H�~����6>'_�|���$��u�y%u��d��x4��bYI����WK                                                        ����~}`VS})̗�X�s2�Z��[��[ڎWF�%��f���Db�eY�:;���*�e��o
  ӫ�U?���R���+�h�hj�*���ZO��n   
                 0�A~�הD��(��q��Zo����lk�qU#D���P�p��0����k0�KM#��M��2P7�8� ���FI��0��݅B�m!��������:7)z?��+���Ͼ\����q�0.$�U��T�_������������vM�,U�RU1_�4%��$�/tJu��iS��\�~��8����:?)��X�w�^                                                        ��-&NJE�2jtP8�O�TbGm�Q���p<,%- C�Ĭ߀��e��:�Y?jQuX]�� ���ԃzP�A=��kV��7�S�g{���DPw6��J��zP�A=��[��Q�0��k�}g�u��ݫ:_��;ԉOu�a��u��q��9��c�>oobL��~�^ԋim/���n-���nU��S[^ԉ_�H���͆|'jغ�߼[~s�4���|
%�?u�����Ư:�����<����.����wkc�?��^k!7�~o��'����/Z}�|·R�s��nf<����ߟ���;�;�W����E��B�zP�W�^����kQuu����P/�f����)Q�<�#v�H�=�J�iwga=`>;���^��z�V�>���mz��[�����ĵa��ef[���*��z/�s
                                                                                       hlQ���Qv�Q3
�Nuv$V�B���l[�0���l$���l�����i<q����kx�H!��Z�v�������M^@�A�x���-��e�G�.��)�UU�]�:IEND�B`
```

Since I'm a novice in perl I couldn't able to figure out what this output is! I guess somewhere I went wrong. Can anyone help me in this issue!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That appears to be correct, that is, if your script is a running on a web server.  Are you trying to get the image into a file or generate from web server to a browser?

Comment: Ahh, it will be good if I get the image to the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this (that would work as CGI)

```
print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
print $myimage->png;
```

You want this (that outputs to a file)

```
open my $fh, '>', 'myfile.png' or die "Couldn't open myfile.png: $!";
binmode $fh;
print $fh $myimage->png;
close $fh;
```

Comment: excellent :D But you have missed the `;` in `die` statement. Thanks for the answer.